# `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension` while trying to install compass

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

I tried this command `sudo gem install compass` and it gave me this error:

```
Fetching: multi_json-1.11.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: compass-core-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: compass-import-once-1.0.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: chunky_png-1.3.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: ffi-1.9.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

The ruby version I am using `ruby 1.9.3p484`

I also tried installing ruby2.0 using `sudo apt-get install ruby2.0` and even that provided the same error

Checked these stackoverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcompass-sass%5D+Failed+to+build+gem+native+extension). They did not provide the answer I require. Most of the answers are for Mac OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest version of ruby [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

Executed the following command (also present in the above url):

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Then executing `rvm -v`:

```
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

And `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
```

Then executing `gem install compass` worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

You could also try just installing the ruby-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```